# Xsl transform process via NANT does not update all xpath's requested

Tags: .net, msbuild, nant, xslcompiledtransform

This is going to be hard for me to explain, but I'll do my best. Add comments for clarifications/additions to anything that I may be missing.

Background Info:

- NANT (build process) version 0.85.2478.0 which executes msbuild
- CruiseControl.NET
- Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit
- .NET Framework 3.5

I am trying to update/modify some settings in our web.config of our web application. We use the NANT code to run our build process which is executed via CruiseControl.NET. We are updating the config files via XslCompiledTransform and using stylesheets and settings files.

Here is what the "UpdateConfig.xslt" file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

      <!-- Set the file output mode -->
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

      <!-- Get the parameters from the calling application -->
      <xsl:param name="defaultSettings" select="'C:\BuildServer\Configuration\ConfigFiles\Defaults.xml'" />
      <xsl:param name="buildTypeSettings" select="'NoFile'" />
      <xsl:param name="environmentSettings" select="'NoFile'" />
      <xsl:param name="projectSettings" select="'NoFile'" />
      <xsl:param name="mode" select="''"/>

      <!-- Load the various ConfigFileSettings XML files. -->
      <xsl:include href="GetSettings.xslt" />
      <xsl:variable name="fileset">
        <xsl:if test="$defaultSettings != 'NoFile'">
          <xsl:element name="File"><xsl:value-of select="$defaultSettings" /></xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$buildTypeSettings != 'NoFile'">
          <xsl:element name="File"><xsl:value-of select="$buildTypeSettings" /></xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$environmentSettings != 'NoFile'">
          <xsl:element name="File"><xsl:value-of select="$environmentSettings" /></xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$projectSettings != 'NoFile'">
          <xsl:element name="File"><xsl:value-of select="$projectSettings" /></xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="Settings">
        <xsl:call-template name="loadSettings">
          <xsl:with-param name="fileset" select="$fileset" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <!-- Define the root node template to distinguish output types. -->
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$mode = 'display'">
            <xsl:call-template name="display" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- Define the default copy template. -->
      <xsl:template match="*|node()|comment()|processing-instruction()" priority="-100">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- Skip certain comments. -->
      <xsl:template match="comment()[contains(., '=tuc0') and contains(., '&lt;publisher')]" />
      <xsl:template match="comment()[contains(., 'add key=&quot;')]" priority="10">
        <xsl:variable name="key" select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'add key=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
        <xsl:if test="count(//add[@key=$key]) = 0"><xsl:copy /></xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- Look up attribute settings in the $Settings block for all attributes. -->
      <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="name() = '@key'"><xsl:copy /></xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>

            <!-- First, build a full xpath to this key as it should appear in settings. -->
            <xsl:variable name="setting">
              <xsl:call-template name="getSetting">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="." />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>

            <!-- Next, get the value from the config file if it's there. -->
            <xsl:variable name="value">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(msxsl:node-set($Settings)//setting[@xpath=$setting]) = 1">
                  <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($Settings)//setting[@xpath=$setting]/@value" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

            <!-- Finally, return the attribute with its new value -->
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="$value" /></xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- Handle SQL Connection Strings -->
      <xsl:template match="@*[(contains(translate(., 'ACDEGILNORSTU ', 'acdegilnorstu'), 'initialcatalog=')
                           or contains(translate(., 'ABDEST ', 'abdest'), 'database='))
                          and not(contains(translate(., 'PROVIDE ', 'provide'), 'provider='))]"
                priority="1">

        <!-- Normalize the connection string -->
    <xsl:variable name="lcString" select="translate(., 'ABCDEGILNORSTU ', 'abcdegilnorstu')" />

    <!-- Get the database from the string -->
    <xsl:variable name="dbname">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($lcString, 'initialcatalog=')">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($lcString, 'initialcatalog='), ';')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($lcString, 'database=')">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($lcString, 'database='), ';')" />
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="SqlDB" select="concat('Initial Catalog=', $dbname, ';')" />

    <!-- Get SQL Settings from $Settings. -->
    <xsl:variable name="SqlAuth">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="translate(msxsl:node-set($Settings)//SqlAuth, 'TRUE', 'true') = 'true'">
          <xsl:text>Trusted_Connection=YES;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>Trusted_Connection=NO;</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="SqlServer">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(msxsl:node-set($Settings)//SqlServer) > 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Data Source=', msxsl:node-set($Settings)//SqlServer, ';')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>.</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="SqlUser">
      <xsl:if test="$SqlAuth = 'Trusted_Connection=NO;' and string-length(msxsl:node-set($Settings)//SqlUser) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('user id=', msxsl:node-set($Settings)//SqlUser, ';')" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="SqlPass">
      <xsl:if test="$SqlAuth = 'Trusted_Connection=NO;' and string-length(msxsl:node-set($Settings)//SqlPass) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('password=', msxsl:node-set($Settings)//SqlPass, ';')" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="SqlApp">
      <xsl:if test="string-length(msxsl:node-set($Settings)//SqlApp) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('APP=', msxsl:node-set($Settings)//SqlApp, ';')" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="concat($SqlServer,$SqlDB,$SqlAuth,$SqlUser,$SqlPass,$SqlApp)" /></xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="getSetting">
    <xsl:param name="node" />
    <xsl:param name="xpath" select="name($node)" />
    <xsl:param name="r" select="'1'" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$node"> <!-- Sets the node as current context -->
      <!-- Handle any special formatting for identifying settings -->
      <xsl:variable name="setting">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="name(..) = 'FTPLocation' and ../@name">
            <xsl:value-of select='concat("[@name=&apos;", ../@name, "&apos;]/@", $xpath)' />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="name() = 'value' and name(..) = 'add' and ../@key">
            <xsl:value-of select='concat("[@key=&apos;", ../@key, "&apos;]/@", $xpath)' />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="not(self::*)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', '@', $xpath)" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', $xpath)" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name(..) = ''">
          <xsl:value-of select="$setting" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="getSetting">
            <xsl:with-param name="node" select=".." />
            <xsl:with-param name="xpath" select="concat(name(..), $setting)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="r" select="$r + 1" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's a portion of the settings file that I'm passing containing some values that work, and also the ones that don't work:

```
<setting xpath="/configuration/General/Settings/add[@key='enableAddrValidationService']/@value" value="true" create="false" dynamic="false" />
<setting xpath="/configuration/General/Settings/add[@key='AddrValidationUrl']/@value" value="bogus" create="false" dynamic="false" />
<setting xpath="/configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint[@name='ValidationServiceSoap']/@address" value="bogus" create="false" dynamic="false" />
<setting xpath="/configuration/applicationSettings/ARTS.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='addrValidationUser']/value" value="bogus" create="false" dynamic="false" />
```

Problem: When I kick off the build for our web application, it is not updating all of the config sections that I want/specify.

I have verified all of the xpath expressions with XmlSpy, Notepad++, and XmlQuire so I know 100% that they are correct.

My only thought as to what is incorrect is that it's in the stylesheet (UpdateConfig.xslt), but this build process was not written by me and I'm having a hard time reading through it.

If anyone has any thoughts as to what is wrong, or how to debug the process better, I'd LOVE to hear them.

Oh, the section that does NOT update is this xpath:

```
<setting xpath="/configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint[@name='ValidationServiceSoap']/@address" value="bogus" create="false" dynamic="false" />
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is too long to read - I fear you won't get any good answers.

Comment: Thanks @skolima I tried to shorten and do some cleanup....

Comment: Have you considered using Config Transforms in Visual Studio 2010? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff801895.aspx

Comment: @BabakNaffas were switching to TFS in the next couple months so there's not really a point in completely writing the current build process. I'd just like to get this one thing fixed so I don't have to remember to update these config settings after each monthly release.